# Photoshop Scripting in vb.net to change the color of an existing vector shape

Tags: color, vector, shapes, photoshop-scripting

I want to open an existing Photoshop file and select a layer called Square.
There is a vector shape in this layer.
I want to change the color of this vector shape. That is all.

I tried many things to approach the vector like:

```
test = docRef.layers("Square")
test = docRef.pathItem("Square")
```

All attempts failed.

I guessed it worked like a text item which I got to work after a full day:

```
  textColor = CreateObject("Photoshop.SolidColor")
        textColor.RGB.Red = 255
        textColor.RGB.Green = 0
        textColor.RGB.Blue = 0
        textItemRef.Color = textColor
```

This absolutely works. I don't understand how a vector shape can be so much more difficult to change.

I am not smart enough to understand Objects.Properties.Methods and such so I need a real world code example. So just referring to some guide won't help me at all. I must see working code in front of me alas. But if you can help, please do so.

Comment: Isnt color the property of a layer not the vector shape?

Comment: Probably. But I do not know how to approach the right object and change its property. I do have links to guides if you can understand those. It mentions all objects and whatnot. Thing is, there are no examples whatsoever so I'm unable to use any.

Comment: If you're going VB scrioting you're pretty much alone. If you're not sure what you're doing, JS script is far more doable

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy nearly same API a bit different call names. But you can pretty much read a java script file and convert it to VB by changing capitalization rules. I prefer to use python over VB instead but no biggie. Its just that i don't do much Photoshop scripting that requires inter process communication (like say you wanted a change in excel register in Photoshop automatically, which is trivial in a COM application but impossible in the jsx engine). I certainly don't do vector stuff in Photoshop..